# Codeigniter 4 image watermark

Tags: image, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm using the codeigniter's Image Manipulation Class and would like to watermark
an image with an another image?

It was working fine in CI3, but I cant find it in CI4.

In the documentation there's only a possibility to watermark with text.  https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/images.html#adding-a-text-watermark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI4 does not support such a feature, you can use this script and make it work with CI4

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.